# appium setup in ubuntu

Tags: 18.04

can someone suggest the complete setup and running a basic program through appium- java in ubuntu

i have tried some steps from the web but my prgm seems to give errors
Exception in thread "main"

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create a new remote session. Please check the server log for more details. Original error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not find 'adb' in ["/home/akil/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb","/home/akil-9792/Android/Sdk/emulator/adb","/home/akil/Android/Sdk/tools/adb","/home/akil-9792/Android/Sdk/tools/bin/adb"]. Do you have Android Build Tools installed at '/home/akil-9792/Android/Sdk'?
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'akil', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.3.0-45-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_242'
Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
remote stacktrace: UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not find 'adb' in ["/home/akil/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb","/home/akil/Android/Sdk/emulator/adb","/home/akil-/Android/Sdk/tools/adb","/home/akil/Android/Sdk/tools/bin/adb"]. Do you have Android Build Tools installed at '/home/akil/Android/Sdk'?
    at getResponseForW3CError (/usr/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-base-driver/lib/protocol/errors.js:804:9)
    at asyncHandler (/usr/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-base-driver/lib/protocol/protocol.js:392:37)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'akil', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.3.0-45-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_242'
Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:208)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:217)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:239)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:41)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.startSession(AppiumDriver.java:336)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.<init>(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:37)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:88)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:98)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.<init>(AndroidDriver.java:94)
    at appium.FirstProgram.main(FirstProgram.java:29)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:186)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not find 'adb' in ["/home/akil-9792/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb","/home/akil/Android/Sdk/emulator/adb","/home/akil-9792/Android/Sdk/tools/adb","/home/akil/Android/Sdk/tools/bin/adb"]. Do you have Android Build Tools installed at '/home/akil/Android/Sdk'?
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'akil', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.3.0-45-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_242'
Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
remote stacktrace: UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not find 'adb' in ["/home/akil-9792/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb","/home/akil/Android/Sdk/emulator/adb","/home/akil-9792/Android/Sdk/tools/adb","/home/akil/Android/Sdk/tools/bin/adb"]. Do you have Android Build Tools installed at '/home/akil/Android/Sdk'?
    at getResponseForW3CError (/usr/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-base-driver/lib/protocol/errors.js:804:9)
    at asyncHandler (/usr/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-base-driver/lib/protocol/protocol.js:392:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$errorHandler$0(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:62)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$0(HandshakeResponse.java:30)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:486)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)
    at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:152)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:531)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:128)
    ... 19 more
```

Comment: The error message asks "Do you have Android Build Tools installed at '/home/akil/Android/Sdk'?" Do you?

Comment: yes i do have 2 build tools there